# Can't find element inside template with querySelector - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

When I try to querySelector an element inside a template tag from external file I get undefined, after a little bit of searching the only solution I found was the 'shadowRoot' but when I tried to use it I got 'shadowRoot is not defined'.

Comment: You can give `querySelectorAll` a shot.

Comment: Which of the dozens of your querySelectors doesn't work?

Comment: i was able to get the `querySelector` to work but not the desired functionality. Make sure your `template` has an activated model as well. 

On a side note - i am really unsure how all this ties together. I don't see a `polymer-element` declaration so you may want to create a codepen or jsfiddle to test this so we can help in a better way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code works fine for me ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fases/2/edit)):

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="tmpl">
  <h1>Hello from {{foo}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var tmpl = document.querySelector('#tmpl');
    tmpl.foo = 'my thing';
  });
</script>
```

I added the `polymer-ready` event since it's generally a good practice to wait for all of your elements to be ready before trying to play around with them.

**edit: The OP wants to know how to find an element inside a template**

To locate an element inside of a template you'll need to `querySelector` using the template's `content` keyword. This is to prevent accidentally selecting things inside of templates (for example, if you were to query selector all `p` tags on the page, you might not want a `p` tag inside of a template that hasn't been stamped out yet).

Here's an example which changes an `h2` inside the `template` ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fases/4/edit))

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="tmpl">
  <h1>Hello from {{foo}}</h1>
  <h2>Another header</h2>
</template>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var tmpl = document.querySelector('#tmpl');
    tmpl.foo = 'my thing';
    var h2 = tmpl.content.querySelector('h2');
    h2.textContent = 'hello world';
  });
</script>
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to say it's find the template tag but not the elements inside the template

Comment: Thank god, looked all over the web for this solution!

Comment: Sorry for unearthing this but, what about if I need to querySelector another polymer component placed inside the template? I tried doing `tmpl.content.querySelector('my-component-name')` and also giving the component an id and selecting it by the id, but none of this worked. Any tip or clue?

Comment: Okei, the actual problem is that I have the following structure: index (component with template) > dashboard (component with template) > main-article-frame (component with template). I want to select this last component, but when I do `querySelector('template')` I found out that I'm receiving the index template. Now I can do `tmpl.content.querySelector('dashboard')` and I'm receiving the correct element, but now I don't know how to reach the main-article-frame component inside dashboard as I can't do again dashboard.content.querySelector since content att doesn't exists on dashboard

Comment: Such a long answer, the simple answer is to use the `.content` property of the `template` element!