# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null Javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list or array of objects that I'm passing to HTML elements through the template. I have a removeItem function. It is removing items. But on the last item, it doesn't hide it. I'm trying to hide the menu when it has no items in it. But on the last item, it gets stuck and doesn't do anything further. The template is causing all the issues. Every other item is other than that template hides. But it doesn't. My shoppingCart.js is getting cartRemove.classList.add("hide") as null. The .hide has the property of display:none.
Errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at hideCart (shoppingCart.js:74)
    at renderCart (shoppingCart.js:54)
    at removeFromCart (shoppingCart.js:68)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (shoppingCart.js:29)
```

[image: Gif of my Problem]

**shoppingCart.js**

```
import items from "./items.json";
import { formatCurrency } from "./utils/formatCurrency.js";

const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const cart = document.querySelector("#cart");
const cartRemove = document.querySelector("[data-cart-item]");

const storeCartContainer = document.querySelector("[data-cart-container]");
const cartItemTemplate = document.querySelector("#cart-item-template");
const cartQuantity = document.querySelector("[data-cart-quantity]");
const cartTotal = document.querySelector("[data-cart-total]");
const cartHide = document.querySelector(".ahmad");
// total.innerHTML = cartTotal.innerText
   

let shoppingCart = [];
const IMAGE_URL = "https://dummyimage.com/420x220";

export const toggleCard = cart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("show");
});

export function setupShoppingCart() {
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
    if (e.target.matches("[data-remove-to-cart-button]")) {
      const id = parseInt(e.target.closest("[data-cart-item]").dataset.itemId);
        removeFromCart(id);
        if (id === null) {
            renderCart()
        }
    }
  });
    renderCart();
}

export function addToCart(id) {

    const existingItem = shoppingCart.find(entry => entry.id === id)
    if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.quantity++
    }
    else {
     shoppingCart.push({ id: id, quantity: 1 });
    }


  renderCart();
}

function renderCart() {
    if (shoppingCart.length === 0) {
        hideCart()
        // hideData()

    }
    else {
        showCart()
        renderCartItems();
    }
}

function removeFromCart(id) {
  const existingItem = shoppingCart.find((entry) => entry.id === id);
  if (existingItem == null) return;
  shoppingCart = shoppingCart.filter((entry) => entry.id !== id);
  renderCart();

    }
    
    function hideCart() {
      cartHide.classList.add("hide");
    
  cartRemove.classList.add("hide"); // This is getting Null
    }
function showCart() {
    cart.classList.remove("hide")

}

function renderCartItems() {
    cartQuantity.innerText = shoppingCart.length;

    const totalCents = shoppingCart.reduce((sum, entry) => {
        const item = items.find((i) => entry.id === i.id);
        return sum + item.priceCents * entry.quantity

    },0)

    cartTotal.innerText = formatCurrency(totalCents / 100)
    storeCartContainer.innerHTML = "";

    shoppingCart.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(items, entry);

        const item = items.find((i) => entry.id === i.id);
        const cartItem = cartItemTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);

        const container = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-item]");
        container.dataset.itemId = item.id;

        const name = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-name]");
        name.innerText = item.name;
        if (entry.quantity > 1) {
            const quantity = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-quantity]");
            quantity.innerText = `x${entry.quantity}`;
        }

        const image = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-img]");
        image.src = `${IMAGE_URL}/${item.imageColor}/${item.imageColor}`;

    const price = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-price]");

    price.innerText = formatCurrency((item.priceCents * entry.quantity) / 100);

    storeCartContainer.appendChild(cartItem);
  });
};
```

**store.index**

```
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="front-page">
        <!-- Section 1 -->
        <section class="section-1">
          <a href="#" id="cart" class="ahmad">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <span data-cart-quantity></span>
          </a>
          <div>
              <div class="menu">
              <div data-cart-container> //Template is under this div
                  <div>
                  </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>Total</h5>
                         <div data-cart-total>
                         </div> </div>
                </div>
        </section>
</body>
</head>
     <template id="cart-item-template">
             <div data-cart-item class="palette">
            <button data-remove-to-cart-button>Close</button>
                <img data-cart-img class="bgc-menu"></img>
                <div class="palette-detail">
                <div data-cart-name class="palette-color"></div>
                <div data-cart-quantity></div>
                <div data-cart-price class="palette-price"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- <span data-cart-amount class="plz">$0.00</span> -->        
        </template>
```

Comment: I am going to guess you're setting your querySelectors before the page has finished rendering

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26027464/6002163), To locate an element inside of a template you'll need to `querySelector` using the template's `content` keyword as below:

```
const template = document.querySelector("#cart-item-template");
const cartRemove = template.content.querySelector("[data-cart-item]");
cartRemove.classList.add("hide"); // Now it works fine
```

Comment: Now it never show any product in menu. Previously I managed to add them and they were visible. Now its just an empty menu.

Comment: @FarhanKhan in fact, I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I am just responding to the specific problem you encountered

Comment: Update: It has been fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference element in your template at the beginning of your script:

```
const cartRemove = document.querySelector("[data-cart-item]");
```

This happens before your template is cloned and placed into DOM, so at this moment element with attribute `data-cart-item` is not found - you get `null` in your `cartRemove` variable.

Try select this element after you instantiate your template in `renderCartItems` function and through a specific instance like you do in these two lines:

```
const cartItem = cartItemTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
const container = cartItem.querySelector("[data-cart-item]");
```